# How can I tell what strain is caused by pyvmomi on vmware?

Tags: python, vmware, stress-testing, vsphere, pyvmomi

I need to make a python script that gathers large amounts of information about vcenters.  I basically call every single diagnostic possible, one after the other, gathering this info into a database daily for machine learning.  This logs into the vcenter via python's pyvmomi and then calls for information about all resource centers, calls for information about all clusters, calls for the hosts on each cluster and information about them, and calls for information about every vm on every host. Where can I see the strain on vcenter?  Where is it hosted?  I guess the issue is I've been assigned a task, and I can gather documentation and get it done, but I dont want to cause strain on very important tools for our business.  How can I be sure this does not cause issues with bandwidth or slow important processes like CPU sharing, memory allocation, and host switching.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the overall stats of the vCenter in the VAMI (vCenter Appliance Management Interface), where you can monitor the CPU and RAM utilization. If you want deeper, more precise, info, it would require logging into the vCenter locally, which is generally not recommended.

vCenter will, in general, handle your queries sequentially. They will queue up if the vCenter can't handle them immediately. The issue is that it will also queue up the other tasks being processed and there's no real way to give tasks a priority.

If you have vROps running in your environment, that might be a better place to pull all of those metrics... assuming they're available there.